# Sending an array of integer values via AJAX post to Flask view

Tags: arrays, ajax, post, flask, serialization

Suppose you have an array in javascript - [1,2,3] and you want to send it via AJAX post to Flask. 
So that in JS:

```
array = new Array()
array.push(1);
array.push(2);
array.push(3);

       var data = JSON.stringify(array);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: alert("messagesent!")
    })
```

And in Flask view :

```
@bp.route('myurl',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def myfunction(address):
    if request.method == "POST":
        FirstSet = request.form['data']
        x = json.loads(FirstSet)
```

However now I dont know how to access the particular values of x list(?), because trying to access it like this :

```
print(x[1])
```

does not work...Thanks in advance for looking at it :)

EDIT: 
The bigger picture: 
I trigger ajax request onclick but after I append all the values that I want to to the array that i want to send. It looks like this:

```
  $("#firstSet").on("click",function(){
      array =[]
      $("#myDiv").children().each(function()
      {
        var star = $(this).children("li.star.selected").length
        array.push(star)
      })
      alert(array)
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl",
        data: {"data":array},
        success: alert("messagesent!")
    })

})
```

This alerted array is not NoneType (and I just get my array values) but what I receive in Flask side is an empty list or NoneType (depenending on how i request it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're sending JSON you should use Flask to get that JSON with the appropriately named [`.get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json):

```
        # ...
        FirstSet = request.get_json()
```

Then `FirstSet` will contain:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Also ensure your AJAX has the appropriate `contentType`:

```
        // ...
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "JSON"
```

---

Edit: I'm including all the Javascript/JQuery that I'm testing with in case it helps you. I wrapped everything in a DOM ready function.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#firstSet").on("click",function(){
            array = [];
            var listItems = $("#myDiv li");
            listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
                var star = $(li);
                array.push(star.length);
            });
            alert(array);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/testing",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: JSON.stringify(array)
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the HTML:

```
  <button id="firstSet" name="firstSet">testing</button>
  <div id="myDiv" name="myDiv">
    <ul id="myList">
      <li data-value="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li data-value="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li data-value="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input id="listChoice" size="15" name="size" type="text" />
  </div>
```

And the Flask code:

```
@bp.route('/testing',methods=["GET","POST",])
def testing():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.get_json())
    return render_template('testing.txt')
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but then my FirstSet is NoneType so its not subscriptable...

Comment: How is your AJAX being triggered? Perhaps you could add the code for that so I can see if there are other issues.

Comment: I just did :) I tried to send the data in a different way now and it is included in the edit (but it still does not work)

Comment: @kikatuso: I updated my answer with the code I'm using to test this out. I hope it helps. Oh, and your URL needs a leading `/` in it as I have included in mine.